# Dynamically Change the resolution of playing video using VLCJ

Tags: vlc, libvlc, vlcj

String mrl= "rtsp://"XX.XX.XX.XX"/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264&resolution=720x480";

I play the video using mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl); It works great. But now I want to dynamically change the resolution of playing video. Example , while playing I have a requirement to change the resolution to 720X560 or something like that.Does it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to know that, this is not possible via an MRL. Either I have to stop and start player with new resolution, else I should manually adjust the JPanl size.